FPDI Error al Abrir documentos Generados por IlovePdf
tengo el error generado en fpdi con los documentos que se han generado en ilovepdf. ya que con otros pdf's se generan normalmente, que solución puedo acudir

Acá un ejemplo que si se puede abrir en versión 1.7


El problema parece es que FPDI no soporta PDF v1.7 (y probablemente es lo que está generando iLovePDF), en el error que publicas sale: ... protected $FileHeader = '%PDF-1.7'....
En la documentación de FPDI dice que por el momento (jun-2024) solo se soporta hasta pdf v1.4.
Posibles soluciones
Verifica si es posible bajar la versión de PDF generado por iLovePDF, usualmente en la configuración de salida (output) se puede cambiar esto. También puedes probar si te deja generar con una versión de salida de PDF con compatibilidad de largo plazo como PDF/A.

Otra opción es convertir el PDF de versión usando una herramienta como Ghostscript (referencia).

Descarga e instala Ghostscript.
Agrega la ruta C:\Program Files\gs\gsXX.XX.X\bin al PATH de sistema (cambiar las X por la versión instalada).
Desde el script PHP:

shell_exec('gswin64 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile="'.$pdf_de_salida.'" "'.$pdf_a_convertir.'"');


Con eso ya podrías seguir procesando el PDF normalmente.

Hola, muchas gracias por responder, quizás es cierto de lo la versión del pdf, he mirado las versiones de los pdf que me deja abrir y son de la versión 1.7, no se que características tendrá el desarrollo de ilovepdf para la creación de la misma, seguiré los pasos que me acabas de recomendar, muchas gracias

@JuanSebastian es probable que algunos pdfs, aunque sean de versiones superiores, tienen una estructura simple y pudieran ser abiertos por la librería. El problema está cuando los quieres manipular. Intenta generar una versión más baja solo para ir descartando cosas. Otra opción puede ser usar otras librerías como pdfparser o pdftk

Referente a la respuesta que te dieron sobre Ghostscript. Puedes usar también FormatFavctory, ambos programas codifican los docs a una versión soportada por mas librerías y dispositivos en caso que busques aplicarles una marca de agua.

Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.. Por favor mira [answer]
